# Hadoop Reducers: How to ensure the reducers are evenly running over a number of nodes

Tags: hadoop, skew, reducers

I have a scenario where I am not sure what the location reduce processors are to occur on.

i) I have an input text file, it has a 1000's of integers in a balanced range between 1 and 4.

ii) Let us suppose there is a 4 node cluster each node with 12 slots, of which 4 are allocated as reducers - giving us 16 total reduce slots

iii) I have set the number of reducers in the driver:

```
jobConf.setNumReduceTasks(4);
```

iii) And finally given I have a partitioner method that is

```
public class MyPartitioner extends Partitioner<Text,Text>{
    @Override
    public int getPartition(Text key, Text value, int numPartitions) {
    return Integer.parseInt(key.toString());
    }       
}
```

1) 
i. 
How do I force it to process the reduce using 1 reducer on each node (leaving the 3 other local reducers idle) rather than more than one reducer running on each node IE how can you ensure that you don't use 4 slots on one Node and have 12 slots on Nodes 2,3&4 idle.

ii. 
Does Hadoop MR manage resource to say: "Node X is the most idle, I'll spawn an reducer there..."

2) if you have skew on a key but intend to group on that, can you spawn multiple reducers for that key, eg add a random integer to a seed value of the value "4" and add 3 additional reducers using the partitioner to process value "4" in reducer 4,5,6 and 7?

```
jobConf.setNumReduceTasks(7);
```

and

```
public class MyPartitioner2 extends Partitioner<Text,Text>{
    @Override
    public int getPartition(Text key, Text value, int numPartitions) {
        int p = Integer.parseInt(key.toString());
        if (p == 4){return p + (new Random()).nextInt(4);}//extra 3 partitions...
        return p;
    }
}
```

Would that work for skew?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't something you can control - the assignment of map and reducer tasks to nodes is handled by the JobTracker.

There's an O'Reilly Answer detailing the specifics of *Task Assignment* in a good amount of detail:

http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/459-anatomy-of-a-mapreduce-job-run-with-hadoop/

The default behaviour is to assign one task per update iteration of the Job Tracker so you shouldn't typically see all reduce tasks being satisfied by the same node - but if your cluster is busy with other tasks and only a single node has available reducer slots then all your reduce tasks may get tasked to that node.

As for handling skew, this will alleviate all data for a single known high volume key possibly being sent to a single node (again there is no guarantee of this), but you'll still have a problem that you'll need to combine the three reducer outputs for this skew key into the final answer.

Comment: Excellent reference - I missed the meaning of those statements originally thanks for highlighting this. I'm assuming that it's a trivial reduce of the key pairs that could be done afterwards

Comment: Yes - identity mapper without a custom partitioner and the same reducer that you are currently using